# How to increment a cell by 1 in a range if the cell next to it is not empty

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I am trying to increment each cell in a given range by 1 if the cell that is next to it has data.

The table is a dummy set of data.
There is an amount in the first three rows of the Loan Amount column.
The Loan Number column should begin at 1 and increase for each cell that is populated.
In this case, the values in Loan Number would be 1, 2, 3.

I have pasted the portion of my code that is relevant to this question.
It is inputting a 1 in each Loan Number cell for each populated cell in Loan Amount.
How can it instead of remaining static at 1, increase by 1 until no other cells in the Loan Amount column have data?

```vb
Dim r as Range, cell As range
Dim mynum As Range

Set r = Range("C29:C48")

mynum = 1
For Each cell in r
    If cell.offset(0,1) <> "" Then
        cell.value = mynum
        mynum = mynum + 1
    End If
Next
```

| Loan Number | Loan Amount |
| --- | --- |
| ---------- | $25000.00 |
| ---------- | $30000.00 |
| ----------- | $35000.00 |
| ----------- |  |

Comment: You can just use regular formula instead of VBA. This is just an option: If your range starts C29, then in cell C29 put `=IF(D29<>"",1,"")` then in cell C30 put `=IF(D30<>"",MAX($C$29:C29)+1,"")`. You can just put the bigger formula in C29 depending on what you have in C28. So basically if the loan amount on the row is not blank, then it will get the max loan number and add 1 to it to continue the sequence.

Comment: For your code though, your problem is your setting `mynum` to a range instead of a number variable. Change `Dim mynum As Range` to `Dim mynum As Long`. I'm surprised it works at all because you should be getting runtime error 91 which means you have some bad error handling going on.

Comment: The code works fine after Simon's suggestion. I additionally prefer `For Each cell In r.Cells` and `If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then`. If it still doesn't work, the reason behind it could be that you have this code in an event procedure. You should post the complete code to get an accurate answer.

Comment: Your code works fine. It does write incremental numbers. But then some other part of your code changes what was done. This might be because your snippet is from a Worksheet_Change event procedure which calls itself with every change it generates. Use `Application.EnableEvents = False` to stop events from occurring while the program writes to the sheet and reset the property to *True* only when all writing is done.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions, I really appreciate it. @VBasic2008, the r.cells seemed to do the trick, thanks!